# Oracle - return only those where the earliest date is present or future

Tags: sql, oracle, date

Let's say I have an "opportunities" table (opportunities can have multiple deadlines) like so:

#### Opportunities

```
id    opp_id    deadline
---------------------------
1     40        20-Jan-2016
2     40        13-Jan-2016
3     40        20-Apr-2016
4     40        13-Apr-2016
5     73        29-Sep-2015
6     95        11-Dec-2016
```

Let's assume today's date is `15-Jan-2016`, what should be returned is:

```
id    opp_id    deadline
---------------------------
6     95        11-Dec-2016
```

But if we assume that today's date is `16-Dec-2015`, the rows I expect to receive are:

```
id    opp_id    deadline
---------------------------
1     40        20-Jan-2016
2     40        13-Jan-2016
3     40        20-Apr-2016
4     40        13-Apr-2016
6     95        11-Dec-2016
```

Basically the logic is to get those opportunities where all of the deadlines are either today or in the future. These are opportunities that I can still apply to because I can still meet the deadline.

How do I go about doing this?

#### EDIT

I guess I should have also clarified that if one of the deadlines for an opportunity has passed, I don't want to get the rest of the deadlines for that particular opportunity. Basically if the earliest deadline has passed, I don't want to retrieve anything for that opportunity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One method uses analytic functions:

```
select o.*
from (select o.*, min(deadline) over (partition by opp_id) as min_deadline
      from opportunities o
     ) o
where min_deadline >= sysdate;
```

You could also do this with `not exists`;

```
select o.*
from opportunities o
where not exists (select 1
                  from opportunities o2
                  where o2.opp_id = o.opp_id and o2.deadline < sysdate
                 );
```

Comment: If the time portion is not relevant, the check should be against `trunc(sysdate)`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it looks like it would work but I have no way of testing it out right now because I'm asking this in advanced. I will be able to test it out by the end of the week or next week. If it works I'll mark your answer as the accepted answer.

Comment: I lied. I made a mock table and tested it out today. Only tested the first one and it works. Just wondering though which method do you suggest in terms of efficiency?

Comment: @PatrickGregorio . . . Oracle has a very good optimizer.  With an index on `opportunities(opp_id, deadline)`, both might have similar performance.  If you have large data, try both and report back.

Comment: I couldn't get the second approach to work. It seems to return all rows regardless of the date I provide. `AND TRUNC(o2.deadline) < TRUNC(TO_DATE('15-Jan-2016', 'DD-Mon-YYYY'))`

Comment: @PatrickGregorio . . . Perhaps it was the missing alias in the `where` clause.

Comment: I still couldn't make it work. I made a pastebin so you can check my entire query: [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/dJ3BHmqY)